# 'Respond' is not a valid script name, the name must end in .js - Microsoft Tutorial

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

'respond' is not a valid script name. The name must end in '.js'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: 'respond' is not a 
valid script name. The name must end in '.js'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web 
request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can 
be identified using the exception stack trace below.

[InvalidOperationException: 'respond' is not a valid script name. The name 
must end in '.js'.]
System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetDebugName(String releaseName) +139
System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.ShouldUseDebugScript(String releaseName, 
Assembly assembly, Boolean isDebuggingEnabled, Assembly currentAjaxAssembly) +31
System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.DetermineResourceNameAndAssembly(ScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean isDebuggingEnabled, String& resourceName, Assembly& assembly) +98
System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrlFromName(ScriptManager scriptManager, IControl scriptManagerControl, Boolean zip, Boolean useCdnPath) +104
System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrlInternal(ScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean zip, Boolean useCdnPath) +603
System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrl(ScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean zip) +182
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterUniqueScripts(List`1 uniqueScripts) +204
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScripts() +465
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +124
System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e) +9883750
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1069
```

I don't know what is causing this error, I have already googled many sites and i simply can't find what is causing it or where is the cause of it. I am following this tutorial on Microsoft site
[[Link]](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/ui_and_navigation/_static/image1.png)
and I have done everything ultil the part where it asks you to download the theme and add to the project. I have done that and when it says to run the code, this error appears. Me and my friend are stucked with this error for the past two days and we can't figure it out.

Comment: It sounds like maybe a bad path reference in your <asp:ScriptManager />. Verify that all of the references are valid file paths.

Comment: I am getting the same error on the same tutorial except I downloaded the code. There were many Nuget packages that needed to be updated but I think I did that but the error remains. I guess I will proceed by doing the tutorial and building the sample that way.

Comment: I got the downloaded code to work. I downloaded from [Getting Started with ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms and Visual Studio 2013 - Wingtip Toys in C# for Visual Studio 2013](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Getting-Started-with-221c01f5?cdn_id=2013-12-16-001) then I used SSMS to delete the database (mdf) files (do not use files explorer to delete databases) then I modified the server in the connection string to be '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB' and then I did **not** update Nuget packages. That worked but I don't know what to do when building the site from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

This very well may be a band aid to a bigger issue that presents itself later but I was able to resolve this same error by commenting out line ~27 of the Site.Master.

```
<%--<asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />--%>
```

I have no idea if that "respond" thing will be needed later in that [(old) tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/ui_and_navigation) or not. Here's hoping not. Also FWIW I did update all my nuget packages before this - didn't seem to affect the 'respond' error either way.